# Write data to S3 compatible with PySpark: which libraries can/should be used?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

We use PySpark in our project and want to store our data in Amazon S3.
We need to read/write/overwrite data with PySpark and
make other operations with files in this bucket in S3 (upload/download/copy/move/...)

### My questions are:

Which Python libraries can and should be used to work with S3 compatible with PySpark?
What are best practices for this?

### What have I tried

- I have found many answers, where AWS SDK is used (e.g.
  [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347959/rename-pyspark-output-files-in-s3),
  [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74658269/copy-and-rename-a-file-key-in-s3-after-being-saved-as-one-csv-with-prefix-part),
  [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71344340/pyspark-write-a-dataframe-to-csv-files-in-s3-with-a-custom-name/71344418#71344418)
  ),
  but it does not seem to be safe:
  as I have learned by [this my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75697225/write-data-in-s3-using-pyspark-after-write-modeoverwrite-wrong-data-is-stor/75705616),
  there is no way to use awswrangler and PySpark safely by the same paths in S3
  (because awswrangler does not respect [directory markers](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/directory_markers.html#background)
  used by PySpark/Hadoop, data written with PySpark can be silently corrupted)
- It seems to be possible to use JVM gateway in PySpark
  (using something like
  `sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(sc._jvm.java.net.URI.create(f"s3a://{MY_BUCKET}"), sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())`),
  but it is unclear if it is a proper way to use PySpark.
- Some other tools by Apache Software Foundation seem to be able to work with files in S3
  (such as
  [S3FileSystem by Apache Arrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.fs.S3FileSystem.html)
  or
  [Apache Airflow](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/s3.html#list-amazon-s3-prefixes)
  ), but I have doubts if it belong to best practices to use them with PySpark for operations with files.
- I'm not sure if
  [Hadoop WebHDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html)
  is suitable, but it seems not to have official python library.

Answer (score 0):

Spark includes [`hadoop-aws`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html) module, so the second bullet is "correct", however, you should ideally add that configuration (along with AWS SDK credentials for the bucket) in the `core-site.xml` file, rather than in-code.

Then, you don't need any Spark JVM config hooks, and you can just use `s3a://` paths directly with Spark read/save actions.